# How to retrieve the sub array elements in meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm working with following document

```
  {
    "_id" : 123344223,
    "firstName" : "gopal",
    "gopal" : [ 
    {
     "uuid" : "123",
     "name" : "sugun"
    }, 
    {
     "uuid" : "456",
     "name" :"kiran"
    }
             ]
}
```

I want to retrieve name from the first document of array and print it in a table...

here is what i have tried

```
Template.table.helpers({
  ProductManager: function () {
    return ProductManager.find({_id:123344223},{gopal:{$elemMatch:{uuid:"123"}}});
  }
})
```

where ProductManager is my collection
and defined in common.js

```
ProductManager = new Meteor.Collection("ProductManager");
```

Here is my template

```
<template name="table">
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>NAME</th>
<th>UUID</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
{{#each ProductManager}}
<tr>
<td>{{name}}</td>
<td>{{uuid}}</td>
</tr>
{{/each}}
</tbody>
</table>
```

when i tried this

```
ProductManager.find({_id:123344223},{gopal:{$elemMatch:{uuid:"123"}}});
```

Iam able get this in mongo shell

```
{
 "_id" : 123344223,
"gopal" : [ 
{
 "uuid" : "123",
 "name" : "sugun"
}
}
```

but cant print name and uuid in the table.......
plzz help me to solve this problem...
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're basically looping through the list of results of the query as opposed to the array. To fix this, query for a specific document:

Use `ProductManager.findOne` instead of `ProductManager.find()`, since you're looking for a specific document.

Loop through everything in the `gopals` array instead of the cursor itself:

```
{{#each ProductManager.gopal}}
....
{{/each}}
```

instead of looping through `{{#each ProductManager}}...`

Comment: heyy, I have one doubt can I use my own db in meteor rather than the default one.The default showing up is "meteor" and i want to use "sugun" as database.

Comment: Thanks, Akshat! The findOne tip worked brilliantly for me.